# Implement which Data Structure for a population management program

Tags: java, data-structures

I'm going to write a java program that will manage data of population for a specific place (name, address, phone, etc...) and has to implement using a data structure.

So my question is which data structure is most practical for this? (It will also has add, display, remove, sorting also).

I'm trying with linkedlist but I just don't feel it the right way. Thanks.

Comment: Why not create a class that stores these properties and then have a collection of that class that feel appropriate?

Comment: Homework? Why does linked list not feel right?

Comment: A collection of Location instances, each one encapsulating name, address, phone, etc. feels right to me.  Is "name" referring to the Location?  Not a Person, correct?

Comment: Would there be some way to implement it *not* using a data structure?

Comment: This question is unanswerable, because it gives no criteria for evaluating what would be best, nor does it describe how the data would be used.

Comment: Difficoult to answere. At least try something before post here

Comment: Thanks folks, I'll try once more and post it here.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very vague shell of something like you described. You seem to not like LinkedLists, so now you can use a Binary Search Tree instead. Look up Binary Search Tree on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree) and implement all the empty methods.

```
public class Population {

    private String name;
    private String address;
    private String phoneNumber;

    public Population(String name, String address, String phoneNumber) {
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    public int compareTo(Population o) {
        return 0;
    }
}


public class MyNode {
    private Population data;
    private MyNode left;
    private MyNode right;

    public MyNode(Population data, MyNode left, MyNode right) {
        this.data = data;
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
    }

    public Population getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(Population data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public MyNode getLeft() {
        return left;
    }

    public void setLeft(MyNode left) {
        this.left = left;
    }

    public MyNode getRight() {
        return right;
    }

    public void setRight(MyNode right) {
        this.right = right;
    }
}

public class MyTree {
    private MyNode root;

    public MyTree(MyNode root) {
        this.root = root;
    }

    public MyTree() {
        this.root = null;
    }

    public void insert(MyNode node) {

    }

    public void remove(MyNode node) {

    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return false;
    }

    public MyNode search(MyNode node) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you, i'll try your method